# How do I retrieve the zoom level from display settings in a C# .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I am working on a touch library, and I have all the code written to detect gestures given certain touch events. The problem is that I need to translate coordinates based on this zoom level, which I already know how to do. I just don't know how to retrieve this value! For the life of me, I can't find anything on the web that explains how to get this programmatically. I have included a picture of the field that I need to get (100/125/150).

[image: The field I need to get programatically]

Comment: You should also be aware if Windows is rescaling your application. Check `SetProcessDPIAware` via msdn or google.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the library I'm using is already doing that, so it might be more of what @jdv-JandeVaan said

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034) for the required manifest changes.